# Kendo sort based a one column when loading

Tags: kendo-grid

I have the code below:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: setData(),
            pageable: false
        },
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230" },
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50},
            { field: "Ca", title: "C.A." , width: 55},
            { field: "TotalScore", title: "Total Score", width: 100},
            { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
        ]
    });
```

---

Now what I want, when the page 1st load I want the data to be sorted by `"TotalScore"`. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , first the kendo dataSource does not have a pageable the grid has it, dataSource has pagesize. now to your problem yes you can . use the sort parameter

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: setData(),
            pageSize: 10,
            sort: { field: "TotalScore", dir: "desc" }
        },
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        pageable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: 230" },
            { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", width: 50},
            { field: "Ca", title: "C.A." , width: 55},
            { field: "TotalScore", title: "Total Score", width: 100},
            { field: "Rank", title: "Rank", width: 60 }
        ]
    });
```

Look at the Kendo Doc for more info http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort